# Remove an sys.service_queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

This is a picture to clarify what I want to delete

[enter link description here](https://3.top4top.net/p_1395cpd0o1.jpg)

I have an orphaned entry in my sys.service_queues table.

When I do

```
    select * from sys.service_queues where name like '%dbo_MessageIn%'
    select * from sys.objects where name like '%dbo_MessageIn%'
```

I see matching results:

```
    dbo_MessageIn_58db7d5a-b255-4012-9b4b-ac8429772af2_Receiver 511601161   NULL    1   0   SQ  SERVICE_QUEUE   2019-10-27 01:06:50.230 2019-10-27 01:06:50.230 0   0   0   0   NULL    NULL    0   1   1   0   0
    dbo_MessageIn_58db7d5a-b255-4012-9b4b-ac8429772af2_Sender   543601275   NULL    1   0   SQ  SERVICE_QUEUE   2019-10-27 01:06:50.233 2019-10-27 01:06:50.247 0   0   0   1   [dbo].[dbo_MessageIn_58db7d5a-b255-4012-9b4b-ac8429772af2_QueueActivationSender]    1   1   1   1   0   0
```

Please help delete this.

Comment: Have you looked at [`DROP QUEUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-queue-transact-sql)?

Comment: I could not apply the example.I've updated the question .I add Picture to illustrate what I want to delete

Answer (score 0):

As Dan said, queues are dropped using [`DROP QUEUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-queue-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

To drop a queue, you will have to drop its attached services first, and to drop a service you need to drop its contract and so on.